# Entity Framework Core and MS Access

Tags: c#, ms-access, entity-framework-core, jet-ef-provider

I'm attempting to use an Access database from a WPF MVVM application using [JetEntityFrameworkProvider](https://github.com/bubibubi/JetEntityFrameworkProvider) and I can't get it to work. I've created the models, created the migrations using Add-Migration but when I run Update-Database, the command never finishes. It does create the database but the only table is MSysAccessStorage. There is a section of the [documentation](https://github.com/bubibubi/JetEntityFrameworkProvider/tree/master/docs) that says

> In order to make the provider work, the table MSysRelationships should
>   be accessible from Administrator

and further says

> This is the default configuration so no needs to make changes. Access
>   since version 2003 has visible system tables so no need to assign
>   rights. The configuration must be done setting the right dual table
>   (very early in your code).
>
> JetConnection.DUAL = JetConnection.DUALForAccdb;

I've tried adding this but I can't figure out where "very early in your code" is. I've added it to the top of my App.xaml.cs and to my database context and neither worked. When I add it I get:

> The name 'DUAL' does not exist in the current context. 
>   The name 'JetConnection.DUALForAccdb' does not exist in the current context.

This is my OnConfiguring in my context

```
protected override void OnConfiguring( DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder )
{
    optionsBuilder.UseJet( @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\<User>\Desktop\New Folder\Staff.accdb;" );
}
```

What am I not doing correctly?

Comment: Why don't you just install SQL Server? The [developer edition is free](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/sql-server/sql-server-downloads). If your planning on developing anything except a quick home test then Access is going to be lacking. You'd be better off learning to use proper tools from the off

Answer (score 4):

The JetEntityFramework provider is not compatible with EF Core.

Instead, use [EntityFrameworkCore.Jet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.Jet/) if you want to use EF Core (same author as JetEntityFramework, not affiliated), or use EF 6 if you want to use JetEntityFramework.